# How to catch the IP adress of the zookeeper-service, and set it correctly into the kafka-broker who needs it, in this example?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have followed the directives of this web site [How To Deploy Apache Kafka With Kubernetes (DZone)](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-deploy-apache-kafka-with-kubernetes) to deploy a *Kafka* broker with its *Zookeeper*. (I've only changed the namespaces names).

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: zookeeper-service
  name: zookeeper-service
  namespace: ecoemploi
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: zookeeper-port
      port: 2181
      nodePort: 30181
      targetPort: 2181
  selector:
    app: zookeeper
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: zookeeper
  name: zookeeper
  namespace: ecoemploi
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zookeeper
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: bitnami/zookeeper:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: zookeeper
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2181
```

But to make it working, the writers of that solution do wait for the cluster to start a first time,
then copy the IP address of `zookeeper-service`

```bash
kubectl get services -n kafka
NAME               TYPE      CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP PORT(S)        AGE
zookeeper-service  NodePort  10.100.69.243  <none>      2181:30181/TCP 3m4s
```

and paste it into the `kafka-broker` deployment file:

```yaml
[...]
    spec:
      hostname: kafka-broker
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
              value: "1"
            - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
              value: 10.100.69.243:2181
            - name: KAFKA_LISTENERS
              value: PLAINTEXT://:9092
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
              value: PLAINTEXT://kafka-broker:9092
[...]
```

Then re-applying `kafka-broker` makes it working.

I'm using this solution, but in a *Vagrant* box it isn't convenient: each time I'm recreating my vagrant, that IP changes...

Is there a solution to get the Cluster IP of that `zookeeper-service` and prepare the correct `KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT` environment variable for `kafka-broker` automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can the service name, which will be the same each time K8s DNS will take care of it.

```
- name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
  value: zookeeper-service
```

**K8s** work that way, internal communication happens over the **service name** use the **IP** if required else **ClusterIP** in nature may changes **IP** with new deployment of **service** or any changes.

DNS resolution will be taken care by Kubernetes(coredns, kubedns), so we just mention the **service-name**.

Here is example for ref : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/

Wordpess connecting to MySQL database with **MySQL** service name **wordpress-mysql** variable **WORDPRESS_DB_HOST**

Comment: It fails. `[2023-05-16 12:30:13,992] ERROR Unable to resolve address: zookeeper-service/<unresolved>:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider)
java.net.UnknownHostException: zookeeper-service: Temporary failure in name resolution`. Do I need to reference a namespace somewhere to qualify `zookeeper.service`?

Comment: that should not be issue, hope you passing `zookeeper-service` add `port` and try once.

Comment: if that's not working got with FQDN option `zookeeper-service.kafka.svc.cluster.local` use as per your setup mostly will be same.

Comment: It still not working. `ERROR Unable to open socket to zookeeper-service.kafka.svc.cluster.local/<unresolved>:2181` when I set `value: zookeeper-service.kafka.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: working for some ppl https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/issues/801 could be issue with DNS, did you tried hitting from busy box POD if DNS resolve working or not ? atleat it's not like expecting the only IP as value not Service account.

Comment: at the time I'm trying, I'm inside the `node01` vm, running a `kubectl apply -f` inside it, immediately. Currently, I have no dns resource in what I've applied. It's only Services, Namespace, PersitentVolume, Deployment, ConfigMap.

Answer (score 1):

I do not suggest following random Dzone articles.

There are projects that (correctly) configure Kafka on Kubernetes for you, with working Helm Charts or Operators such as [Strimzi](https://strimzi.io), [Confluent CFK Operator](https://docs.confluent.io/operator/current/co-deploy-cfk.html), or [Banzai Koperator](https://github.com/banzaicloud/koperator).

Also worth mentioning that Kafka doesn't require Zookeeper anymore, though the above projects may continue to support that model until the next major Kafka release where it'll be removed completely.

Comment: Yes it is flawed. The dns isn't working at all. I had to change Vagrantfile entirely to make it working, from another provider.

Comment: It should work out of the box, but that may depend if you are running CoreDNS service - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/